# Upload synonym file to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I am new to Elastic Search and trying to work with synonyms. I have a synonym.txt file but not sure how to upload it to ES. IF there is anyone to help out, it would be great

Comment: Which method have you used to install/setup elasticsearch?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can upload it during index creation in the `settings`, example :

```
{
  "settings": {
   "analysis": {
    "filter": {
     "my_synonym": {
      "type": "synonym",
      "synonym_path": "./synonym.txt"
      }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Read more about it in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#analysis-synonym-tokenfilter)

Comment: The setting is `synonyms_path` and refers to a path relative to the Elasticsearch configuration directory. Creating an index doesn't upload this file. It must already exist.